# Reference variables in java

Tags: java, android

I have a question about references variables.

I know that declaring a reference variable doesn't create the object.

But in Android, if I write:

```
 Button button;

//button.(methods are seen)

 button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1); //Does this instantiate the object?

//button.(methods are seen)
```

How am I able to access the methods of Button class without explicitly creating the object at either the first and second commented lines?

For example, I can do:

```
 button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        finish();
    }
});
```

I don't understand how it works.

Comment: `(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1)` Here object is referenced and not created. 

Without either reference or creating object how can you access the functionalities of the object? That's voilation to fundamentals of programming.

Comment: That code will not compile! Did you even try?

Answer (score 2):

When you use `<Button></Button>` in your xml, you are creating a Button object (android creates it for you). When you use the method`findViewById` you are obtaining a reference to the created `Button`. So you can access public methods of the `Button` class.

Comment: your welcome. 
but I think you shouldn't ask this type of questions here. try googling before asking in stackoverflow. :)

Comment: You said that when you use findViewById you are obtaining a reference to created Button is the reference is stored in button variable?

Comment: Ok I am working on object creation by making some researches on google:D

Comment: I can't get your question. what do yo mean "is the reference is stored in button variables"?